# how to show tasks in TFS delivery plans

Tags: tfs

we have a TFS with many tasks and want to see them on the TFS delivery plan, how can I do it?
in the delivery plan I can only see stories and bugs, but I'm more interested on tasks..

Answer (score 0):

Generally, only the selected backlog level work items can be displayed in delivery plans. But **Task** is not in any of the backlog level categories (Epics-`Microsoft.EpicCategory`, Features-`Microsoft.FeatureCategory`, Stories-`Microsoft.RequirementCategory`).

So, to display Task in Delivery plans, you can try to add **Task** to `Microsoft.RequirementCategory`. You need to edit the Task WIT definition to support planning tools. See [Add a WIT to track it like a requirement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/add-wits-to-backlogs-and-boards#add-a-wit-to-track-it-like-a-requirement) for details.

But it will conflict with the original/default behaviour of Task work item. So, if you insist on display Task in delevery plans you can try add a new type work item based on the existing **Task** wit, then custom it as needed.

Comment: @Luis Molina Have you resolved this issue? any update?